# (GAE-Standard+Java11) Sessions with multiple instances running

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, spring-security

I have deployed my spring boot application on GAE, Java 11, Standard Environment. As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences#creating_an_appyaml_file) for Java11 we need to use `app.yaml` for configuring the instances.

I wanted to know as to how I can enable sharing of sessions between instances. As per my research, Earlier we could simply solve this problem by setting `sessions-enabled` and `async-session-persistence` in `appengine-web.xml`. With `appengine-web.xml` gone, what is the equivalent way of doing this in `app.yaml`.

Use case that i am trying to achieve is :

1. Using spring security (Unfortunately i get logged out when according to me the request of the same user goes to another instance.)
2. Storing the user retrieved from DB in a `@SessionScoped` variable so as to avoid multiple DB calls.

Any help here would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went through a lot of documentation, but I believe that this is not inside the app.yaml configuration reference.

Alternatively, I could find that you could use session affinity in order to use a instance to reply always the requests of a same user, this can be enabled in your app you can use the next tag in your app.yaml according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-websockets-and-session-affinity#session_affinity).

```
network:
  session_affinity: true
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for doing the exploration, As per the documentation the session affinity bit is present only for the Flexible environment, but anyhow there is no harm in trying this out on standard, I will try this out and revert back if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that this will not be possible to achieve with the new way that java 11 is being configured now (and without you having to implement a session solution other than rely on the config file.)

So in here, my suggestion would be to open a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) with them so that this is incorporated to java 11 runtime or to GAE.

Comment: This has worked fine for me for working with attributes of HttpSession in a Spring Boot application with java 11 and .jar packaging in App Engine Standard.